# How to see how many reports/ data sources/ pages within reports in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to do an audit of our Google Data Studio account so how many reports have been created, how many slides in each report, how many data connectors, etc?

Any documentation I get on this relates to connecting Data Studio to Google Analytics to see report performance data so how many views, sessions, etc. However this does not achieve the above. Has anyone been able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have the G-Suit, then the Data Studio API gives you an overview of the created reports. But not the page numbers https://developers.google.com/datastudio/api/reference/types#AssetType

For more details use for each report your google analytics ID. There you obtain an detailed overview of the usage and also can count the different pages.

Comment: I have not used this before. Do you have any instructions that I could follow to set it up?